# USB HDD power off after shutdown

Tags: 12.04, usb, hard-drive, shutdown

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my external USB HDD and from the begining when I power off my ubuntu
my USB HDD also power off 5 seconds later than my computer. Its good for me.
But after some updates Ubuntu USB HDD stay power on.
Where I can set this ?

I make changes according Your help but problem is again
and after restart I have ..power/control in mode ON.
I am not sure but I think that my HDD is usb1.

```
petat@mujlin:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:342e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 152d:2509 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539 SuperSpeed SATA II 3.0G Bridge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
petat@mujlin:~$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
2000
petat@mujlin:~$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control
auto
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to unload the EHCI controller (USB 2.0) before shutdown.

1. Check your ID (Bus/Device/Function), use these commands in Terminal:

   ```
   cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/
   ls -1
   ```

   For example, my outputs are:

   ```
   0000:00:02.1
   bind
   module
   new_id
   remove_id
   uevent
   unbind
   ```

   The first one is my ID. Check your ID
2. Now you need to create the script, use this command in Terminal   (rc0.d is used when you shutdown your computer)

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/rc0.d/K99mycustomscript
   ```

   Add this line:

   ```
   echo -n "YOUR_ID" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
   ```

   For example, in my case it's:

   ```
   echo -n "0000:00:02.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
   ```
3. Save and close gedit
4. Make your script executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/K99mycustomscript
   ```
5. Now if you want to run your script on reboot (rc6.d):

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/rc0.d/K99mycustomscript /etc/rc6.d/K99mycustomscript
   ```

[References](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out in which USB port your drive is plugged in.

Use `lsusb` command. 
For my Kingston flash drive it shows **Bus 001**, which means it is on **usb1**:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13fe:1d00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. DataTraveler 2.0 1GB/4GB Flash Drive / Patriot Xporter 4GB Flash Drive
```

Then check the file (use your usb number for `X`):

```
 less /sys/bus/usb/devices/**usbX**/power/control
```

I have `auto` in mine. You might have `on`, in there. Try changing it to `auto` with your text editor, like this, for example:

```
 sudo nano /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control
```

Also, check the `.../power/autosuspend_delay_ms` file. Make sure there is no `-1` written to it. Mine has 2000 in it, which gives 2 seconds to the USB device before turning it off.

There is relevant information about USB power management [at this site](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is "device/battery" charging facility that is keeping power to USB devices after shutdown.  The keyboard/mouse wake from suspend facility can also hold power to the USB ports, since it needs these devices powered up, obviously.

If you don't use you computer in either of these ways, have a look in BIOS and disable all features that are designed to keep power on the USB ports.

Answer (score -1):

This might happen if you use the USB drive on USB 3.

Swapping over to USB 2 worked for me.